# Quick replies in Microsoft Bot Framework, web chat platform

Tags: botframework

I'm using MS Bot framework with Facebook & web chat platforms.
There is any way to use quick replies in the web chat?

because MS bot framework doesn't support quick replies for the web chat framework.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use suggested actions, which disappear when clicked. Here's a sample, modified from the [Bot Framework documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-add-suggested-actions), on how to do that:

```
var reply = activity.CreateReply("Hi, do you want to hear a joke?");
reply.Type = ActivityTypes.Message;
reply.TextFormat = TextFormatTypes.Plain;

reply.SuggestedActions = new SuggestedActions()
{
    Actions = new List<CardAction>()
    {
        new CardAction(){ Title = "Yes", Type=ActionTypes.ImBack, Value="Yes" },
        new CardAction(){ Title = "No", Type=ActionTypes.ImBack, Value="No" },
        new CardAction(){ Title = "I don't know", Type=ActionTypes.ImBack, Value="IDontKnow" }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [HeroCard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-add-rich-card-attachments) in order to implement such functionality. HeroCard can be used globally on bot framework and the appearance of the dialog is up to platform's design.

For your case you could use something like this:

```
 private async void HiMessage(IDialogContext ctx)
    {
        List<CardAction> list = new List<CardAction>();
        list.Add(new CardAction { Title = "Yes", Type = ActionTypes.ImBack, Value = "yes" });
        list.Add(new CardAction { Title = "No", Type = ActionTypes.ImBack, Value = "no" });
        list.Add(new CardAction { Title = "I don't know", Type = ActionTypes.ImBack, Value = "dontknow" });
        HeroCard hero = new HeroCard();
        hero.Title = "Hi";
        hero.Text = "Do you want to hear a joke?";
        hero.Buttons = list;
        var msg = ctx.MakeMessage();
        msg.Attachments.Add(hero.ToAttachment());
        await ctx.PostAsync(msg);
    }
```

You can further explore the rich cards from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bots/card-sample-bot)

Comment: Thanks, but I want the buttons to disappear after the user clicks them.. Facebook Messenger has Quick reply which disappear right after the hit, but web chat doesn't..